# Grunt task not running

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, copy

I'm working on a grunt script to copy some files from 'dev' into 'dist' and modify the folder structure slightly. There are html files present inside dev/html/eas1/ and dev/html/eas2. The script uses grunt.config.set in order to change the src and dest locations of the copy and the script is running without errors, but nothing is being copied over. Can anyone help?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        projectCodes: {
            eas: ['eas1', 'eas2', 'eas3', 'eas4', 'eas5', 'eas6']
        },

        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    src: 'dev/eas/html/eas1/*',
                    dest: 'dist/eas/eas1/html/',
                    filter: 'isFile'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.registerTask('dev', function(p) {

        var projectCodes = grunt.config.get('projectCodes');

        for(code in projectCodes[p]) {

            grunt.config.set('copy.main.files.0.src', 'dev/'+p+'/html/'+projectCodes[p][code]+'/*');
            grunt.config.set('copy.main.files.0.dest', 'dist/'+p+'/'+projectCodes[p][code]+'/html/');
            grunt.task.run('copy:main');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Turns out the following question is a solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931003/how-to-use-dynamic-values-in-grunt-tasks-called-from-inside-a-foreach